# How to solve "/dev/sdaX clean files blocks" problem in Ubuntu 16.04, when shutdown or reboot the system?

Tags: 16.04, ssd

I'm not an advanced user of ubuntu, so I need some help to solve this issue.

When I try to shutdown or reboot my PC, I got an error below:

```
/dev/sda6: clean, xxxx/XXXXXXX files, yyyyyyy/YYYYYYY blocks
```

and the system never shutdown or reboot.
I saw so many questions about this. I just saw some workarounds, but an answer about how to solve this.
Some users are doing a downgrade to 14.04, and waiting for a new version to fix this.

So, I'd like to know if this is the best approach to do. Should I have to do a downgrade also?
What about the 16.10 version? This problem still occurs in the new version of Ubuntu?

PS.: I'm using an SSD disk.

**--- Edit:**

Here's some output when the problem occurs:

```
[ XXXXX.XXXXX ] [TIM] Buffer eviction failed
[ XXXXX.XXXXY ] INFO: task kworker/2:3:214 blocked for more than 120 seconds
[ XXXXX.XXXXZ ]       Not tainted 4.8.0-39-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[ XXXXX.XXXXT ] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message
[ XXXXX.XXXXY ] INFO: task plymouthd:4092 blocked for more than 120 seconds
[ XXXXX.XXXXZ ]       Not tainted 4.8.0-39-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[ XXXXX.XXXXT ] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message
```

These 6 messages above repeat constantly.

PS.2: I'm using a Dell Inspiron 15 5548

**--- Edit 2:**

My Dell Inspiron 15 5548 has a intel CPU, with core i7. So I installed the `intel-microcode` in terminal: `sudo apt-get install intel-microcode -y`

them, I reboot my pc, and run the dmesg command as follows:

```
$ dmesg | grep microcode
[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x22, date = 2015-09-11
[    1.247070] microcode: sig=0x306d4, pf=0x40, revision=0x22
[    1.247106] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.01 <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
```

**--- Edit 3:**

This is my output, when I run the `ps xu` command:

```
$ ps xu
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
celsoag+  1864  0.0  0.0  45380  5080 ?        Ss   06:42   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
celsoag+  1866  0.0  0.0 145216  1972 ?        S    06:42   0:00 (sd-pam)
celsoag+  1871  0.0  0.0 212784  7728 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
celsoag+  1873  0.2  0.1 433068 26804 ?        Ssl  06:42   0:00 cinnamon-session --session cinnamon
celsoag+  1881  0.0  0.1 167228 18284 ?        S    06:42   0:00 touchegg
celsoag+  1937  0.0  0.0  11140   316 ?        Ss   06:42   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch cinnamon-session-cinnamon
celsoag+  1940  0.0  0.0  43600   372 ?        S    06:42   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch cinnamon-session-cinnamon
celsoag+  1941  0.3  0.0  43624  3968 ?        Ss   06:42   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
celsoag+  1953  0.0  0.0 281768  6400 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
celsoag+  1958  0.0  0.0 419960  7156 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -o big_writes
celsoag+  1967  0.0  0.0 353840 10272 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-launcher
celsoag+  1973  0.0  0.0  42900  3992 ?        S    06:42   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf --nofork --print-address 3
celsoag+  1975  0.0  0.0 206868  5016 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-registryd --use-gnome-session
celsoag+  1992  0.8  0.2 970456 45156 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/cinnamon-settings-daemon
celsoag+  1997  0.1  0.0 516380 12568 ?        S<l  06:42   0:00 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
celsoag+  2004  0.0  0.0 178784  5024 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
celsoag+  2008  0.0  0.0 304008  9680 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
celsoag+  2040  0.0  0.0 266964  5076 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
celsoag+  2045  0.0  0.0 410960  9288 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
celsoag+  2051  0.0  0.0 279160  5456 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
celsoag+  2056  0.0  0.0 264884  5240 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor
celsoag+  2060  0.1  0.1 195752 31648 ?        S    06:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/cinnamon-launcher
celsoag+  2061  0.0  0.0  22372  1252 ?        S    06:42   0:00 syndaemon -i 1.0 -t -K -R
celsoag+  2063  0.0  0.0 509004 13788 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cinnamon-settings-daemon/csd-printer
celsoag+  2069 13.4  1.4 1707680 239108 ?      Sl   06:42   0:06 cinnamon --replace
celsoag+  2077  0.1  0.1 338140 21284 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
celsoag+  2078  0.0  0.1 1247676 17584 ?       Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
celsoag+  2079  0.0  0.0 356812  8292 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicator-bluetooth-service
celsoag+  2081  0.0  0.0 377716  9896 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
celsoag+  2086  5.3  0.5 1292224 89516 ?       Sl   06:42   0:02 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplication-service
celsoag+  2090  0.1  0.0 442784 11616 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-power/indicator-power-service
celsoag+  2095  0.1  0.1 683316 17740 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-keyboard/indicator-keyboard-service
celsoag+  2096  0.5  0.2 712400 38372 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 nemo -n
celsoag+  2107  0.3  0.2 573308 37784 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 nm-applet
celsoag+  2111  0.1  0.1 631388 23696 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry
celsoag+  2113  0.2  0.1 427780 31748 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/cinnamon-killer-daemon
celsoag+  2117  0.1  0.1 260156 32424 ?        S    06:42   0:00 touchegg &
celsoag+  2122  0.0  0.0 757216 15092 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-sound/indicator-sound-service
celsoag+  2134  0.0  0.0  68652  5508 ?        S    06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/gconfd-2
celsoag+  2154  0.0  0.0 371252  8268 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.1 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
celsoag+  2169  0.3  0.3 870460 60492 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory
celsoag+  2177  0.0  0.0 193328  5244 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
celsoag+  2188  0.2  0.3 896216 51716 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess --factory contacts --bus-name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.Calendarx
celsoag+  2199  0.2  0.3 880464 52528 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess --factory local --bus-name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.Calendarx216
celsoag+  2200  0.0  0.1 705168 22072 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory
celsoag+  2207  0.0  0.1 854396 19668 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory-subprocess --factory local --bus-name org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Subprocess.Backend.AddressBo
celsoag+  2290  0.3  0.2 494156 38320 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
celsoag+  2291  0.8  0.3 661132 50224 ?        Sl   06:42   0:00 cinnamon-screensaver
celsoag+  2300  0.0  0.0  29776  5196 pts/0    Ss   06:42   0:00 bash
celsoag+  2312 15.5  1.0 1041108 171524 ?      SLl  06:43   0:05 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
celsoag+  2318  0.0  0.0  14516   832 ?        S    06:43   0:00 cat
celsoag+  2319  0.0  0.0  14516   696 ?        S    06:43   0:00 cat
celsoag+  2322  0.2  0.3 378720 49344 ?        S    06:43   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-crash-reporter=5357f5ee-a14f-4e6e-8ab0-76cec7d6adf6,
celsoag+  2323  0.0  0.0  26976  4872 ?        S    06:43   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
celsoag+  2326  0.0  0.0 378720 12080 ?        S    06:43   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --enable-crash-reporter=5357f5ee-a14f-4e6e-8ab0-76cec7d6adf6,
celsoag+  2373  3.0  0.5 457092 97476 ?        Sl   06:43   0:01 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-process --enable-features=AutofillProfileCleanup<AutofillProfileCleanup,BlockSmallPluginContent<PluginPowerSa
celsoag+  2377  0.0  0.0 382936 13584 ?        S    06:43   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=gpu-broker                                                                                                       
celsoag+  2405  0.6  0.4 755072 79196 ?        Sl   06:43   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-features=AutofillProfileCleanup<AutofillProfileCleanup,BlockSmallPluginContent<PluginPowerSaver
celsoag+  2434  0.2  0.4 729976 71612 ?        Sl   06:43   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-features=AutofillProfileCleanup<AutofillProfileCleanup,BlockSmallPluginContent<PluginPowerSaver
celsoag+  2442 12.3  0.9 1592440 151076 ?      Sl   06:43   0:04 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-features=AutofillProfileCleanup<AutofillProfileCleanup,BlockSmallPluginContent<PluginPowerSaver
celsoag+  2472  1.2  0.4 1050632 73552 ?       Sl   06:43   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-features=AutofillProfileCleanup<AutofillProfileCleanup,BlockSmallPluginContent<PluginPowerSaver
celsoag+  2508  7.1  0.6 781220 104852 ?       Sl   06:43   0:01 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --enable-features=AutofillProfileCleanup<AutofillProfileCleanup,BlockSmallPluginContent<PluginPowerSaver
celsoag+  2516  0.0  0.1 441328 17192 ?        Sl   06:43   0:00 zeitgeist-datahub
celsoag+  2521  0.0  0.0   4508   792 ?        S    06:43   0:00 /bin/sh -c /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-maybe-vacuum; /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
celsoag+  2525  0.0  0.0 405500  6252 ?        Sl   06:43   0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
celsoag+  2532  0.0  0.0 310844  9612 ?        Sl   06:43   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zeitgeist-fts
celsoag+  2570  1.8  0.1 243944 31372 ?        Sl   06:43   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
celsoag+  2612  0.0  0.0  44464  3332 pts/0    R+   06:43   0:00 ps xu
```

As you see, I have plymouthd and kworker:

```
celsoag+  2616  0.0  0.0  21312   936 pts/0    S+   06:43   0:00 grep --color=auto plymouthd
celsoag+  3240  0.0  0.0  21312  1028 pts/0    S+   06:47   0:00 grep --color=auto kworker
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55071/discussion-on-question-by-celso-agra-how-to-solve-dev-sdax-clean-files-blocks).

Comment: That message `/dev/sda6: clean` has nothing to do with the issue. That's just a quick filesystem check during boot, and "clean" means good.

Comment: @wjandrea, the problem is, my system never shutdown, and the `plymouthd` and `kworker` still being blocked. So, I installed the new version of ubuntu (`16.04.2LTS`) without `cinnamon` and `nemo`, and unfortunately, my system still hanging when I shutdown my notebook.

I'm considering to do a downgrande or install the new version (`16.10`).